# PHP Short Code on String

Tags: php, string, google-maps, str-replace, explode

I am currently using:

```
$string = str_replace("[map]","<a target=\"_new\" href=\"https://maps.google.com/?q=",
$string);
$string = str_replace("[/map]","\">Click Here to View the Map</a>",$string);
echo $string;
```

This allows my users to enter

> " some text [map] full address [/map] some text some more text [map] full address number 2 [/map]"

And it will automatically create the google map link for it.

What I am trying to do now, is change " Click Here to View the Map " so it displays the " full address" instead. ( Whatever text the user places between the [map][/map] tags)

This would be easy if I did not have multiple [map] items contained within the $string.

Any suggestions or am I approaching this wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where comes the "full address number" from?

Comment: Sorry, the full address is whatever text the user puts between the [map][/map] tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then I would use a regular expression:

```
$string = 'text [map]link[/map] and another text';
$string = preg_replace('/(\[map\])(.*?)(\[\/map\])/','<a target="_new" href="https://maps.google.com/?q=$2">$2</a>',$string);
```

They seem a bit complicated at first glance, but are very helpful in this case. If you’re interested, here is some further reading: http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. :)